# how to display indoor map with mapbox on android studio

Tags: android, mapping, mapbox

I am new to mapbox mapping, I am currently working on how to indoor map with mapbox android sdk. Can anyone briefly or clearly guide me the what-to-do? I have an image of my building floor plan and I also have a fully edited OSM format map. But i know mapbox is using GEOJSON format. May i know how should I start with displaying my building indoor map on my android apps?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine plotting line by line to make a rectangle. And then add another one - until you have the building floor

To start off, you can go to: https://geojson.io/
Choose the line tool and start tracing lines. This will give you an idea of how GeoJSON structure works - as this shows you a real time snippet of how the GeoJSON looks like after each line is drawn.

After that, you can look at:
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/floor-plan/

to add your floorplan to your map. This is a very good example code to use, especially if your floorplan has multiple levels.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer I will be sure to check it out!

Comment: So basically the osm format map is not useful anymore?

Comment: Looking around, it seems you can still use the osm, but still have to convert them to geoJSON. Check this: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/overpass-turbo/

Comment: hey there, thank you for still trying to help me out. Right now I have converted my osm file to geojson but another problem is how to load into the android sdk mapbox.